# Download File from FirebaseStorage using the file's downloadUrl. (Android, Java)

Tags: java, android

How do I download a specific file from the FirebaseStorage using its downloadURL?

(e.g. https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/smart-edubox-90c5d.appspot.com/o/uploaded_files%2Fpdf_files%2F08-11-2022_15%3A43%3A02_dummy.pdf?alt=media&token=f68e7403-0cb7-4c86-9799-1c47fffd9cb5 )

I load the image, pdf, and text file into a RecyclerView. When I tap on a CardView (in the RecyclerView) I will be redirected to the file's corresponding download url in a browser. How should I do it so that instead of opening it in a web browser, the file would be downloaded to a specific folder in the user's phone.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To download any file from Url you can simply use the Download Manager of Android
this is code to download file from URL

```
String[] PERMISSIONS = {
            android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
    };

if (!hasPermissions(activity.this, PERMISSIONS)) {
            String url = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/smart-edubox-90c5d.appspot.com/o/uploaded_files%2Fpdf_files%2F08-11-2022_15%3A43%3A02_dummy.pdf?alt=media&token=f68e7403-0cb7-4c86-9799-1c47fffd9cb5";
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
            request.setDescription("Some descrition");
            request.setTitle("Some title");
            // in order for this if to run, you must use the android 3.2 to compile your app
            request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "name-of-the-file.pdf");

            // get download service and enqueue file
            DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            manager.enqueue(request);
        }
```

this is permission for Storage

```
public static boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String... permissions) {
        if (context != null && permissions != null) {
            for (String permission : permissions) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

and your manifest permissions will be

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: What method should I import for getSystemService in DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE); ?

Comment: import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.app.DownloadManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;

Comment: Oh wait nvm, I forgot to add context before it. I forgot I'm not coding inside an Activity.

Comment: this is my import there is nothing specific for getSystemService its default import for android simply ALT+ENTER

Comment: ok you are using adapter then you must include context

Comment: Oh no, it is inside the Handler Class for the RecyclerView.

Comment: i edited my answer after seeing recyclerview in your question